# build-helper-maven-plugin: deploy a file without version indicator

Tags: maven, artifact

I have a project where I generate a *pseudo* binary executeable. I want maven to deploy this file alongside with the generated jars.

In general this works, but the deployed file also has a version tag like `filename-x.z.y`.

I have the following setup:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifacts>
                    <artifact>
                        <file>target/filename</file>
                        <type>.</type>                                  
                    </artifact>
                </artifacts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What I need is just `filename` without the version. Since I can not find any *usefull* documentation about the plugin I ask here for help.

Comment: First why using the build-helper-plugin because I assume you already generating the file during a maven build? So why not doing `mvn deploy` furthermore the naming system is simply: `artifactId-Version.ext` and that can not being changed...

Comment: @khmarbaise your assumption is correct. I use this plugin because the file would not deploy otherwise (being generated with really-executable-jar-maven-plugin). Maybe I need to look into this.
But you answered my main question: it can not be changed, maybe want to write Answer, so I can check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For artifacts which will be deployed to a maven repository the naming rules are hard. You can not change the given format `artifactId-version.Ext` ...